# How to display code snippets incrementally?

Tags: beamer, verbatim, minted, code, pythontex

I want to use BEAMER and PythonTEX to prepare a slideshow that contains a lot of code. When displaying a code snippet in console mode I would like to show one line at a time. I'm struggling to achieve something like `\begin{pyconsole}[<+->}` to no avail. This is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Demo}
The following code should appear progressively instead of the entire snippet at once
\begin{pyconsole}
from math import sin, pi
theta = pi/2
x = sin(theta)
print(f'sin(theta) = {x}')
\end{pyconsole}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I've tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195078/beamer-and-pause-with-pythontex) to insert a `\pause` at the end of each line in a `pyconsole` environment but I got the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@pytx@pycon@default@default already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 \newcounter{pytx@pycon@default@default}
                                            
?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get [@G. Poore's excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195078/beamer-and-pause-with-pythontex/195135#195135) to work. I'm posting this just in case it could be helpful for someone else. The following tweaks did the trick:

- The error vanished by simply removing the line `\newcounter{pytx@pycon@default@default}`.
- Changed `\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{#1\pause}}` to `\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{\pause#1}}` so that the `\pause` was inserted *before* each console command rather than *after* each console command.

**Output:**

[image: animated result]