# Customize minted environment w.r.t IDLE

Tags: minted, python, customize

I'm writing a document using Python code and I want to make it like IDLE style. With `minted`, we can custom the environment so that each line of code starts with >>>, however, I want >>> appears only in commands, not in the result.

Here is my MWE:

```
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{width = 16cm, height =24cm}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}
\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{>\/>\/> #1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.98}
\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,1}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{breakable=true, listing engine=minted, 
listing only, minted language=#2, minted style=default, 
minted options={gobble=0, breaklines=true, breakafter=,, fontsize=\small, numbersep=8pt, #1}, 
boxsep=0pt, left skip=0pt, right skip=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=3pt, bottom=3pt, arc=0pt, leftrule=0pt, 
rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=1pt, toprule=1pt, colback=bg, colframe=bl!10, enhanced}

%\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mintedbox}{python}
sentence = "Python is powerful and easy to learn"
sentence.split()
['Python', 'is', 'powerful', 'and', 'easy', 'to', 'learn']
\end{mintedbox}
\end{document}
```

In this MWE, `\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{>\/>\/> #1}` helps to put >>> at every first place of each line.

How can we customize to make it like IDLE as follows?

[image]

Thanks for reading.

Comment: See section 3.4 (using different styles) of the `minted` package (https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf). `minted` uses `pygmentize` Python package to do the actual work. To create your own style, you may refer to this page: https://pygments.org/docs/styledevelopment/

Comment: You could take a look a `pyconsole` from the PythonTeX package, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580926/how-to-display-code-snippets-incrementally